# MS Test Report varies when running with Visual Studio Test and versus when running with Run Function Test Task

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest, tfsbuild, vstest, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am running a suite of MSTest and each of the test is designed to accept a datasource which is an xls file

For example,  I have a MSTest which has 20 rows (When I run Visual Studio Test Task, I get a report like below )

[image]

[image]

But when I run the test using Run Functional Test Task ( which is in a distributed fashion across VMs ), I get a result file like below and this says only one test is executed (though 20 test cases get executed and able to view the result in a trx file ) 
But not available in tfsonline...

[image]

[image]

The Issue is I need to run the test in a distributed fashion using Run Functional Test task but I wish a report like the former which has individual test details.

I am fully confused as How I can achieve this.

Any pointers on what I am missing here. Any info will be much helpful...

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be reproduced on our side. The test output transferred to the build machine is incorrect for your scenario (running a suite of MSTest and each of the test is designed to accept a datasource which is an xls file) , please submit a feedback at website below:

http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Comment: I am not sure about this answer. Is this an enhancement from Microsoft end which they need to cater??

Comment: After submit the feedback, Microsoft product team will check this issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: I will report this issue on my side too.